# Manipulate (group, transpose, etc.) a shapefile's table with PyQGIS/Python and export as CSV?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, pandas

I'm making a QGIS processing plugin that copies [ArcMap's Tabulate Area](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool which basically calculates, in my case, how much (in sqm) of each land cover classification are there in each municipality.

The goal is to add a code in my existing plugin script (below) that manipulates the output shapefile's table (group cells with same values, transpose column values as column headers, etc.) just like with Pandas. I've checked the [PyQGIS API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/) and can't find any classes that do this.

Right now, the result is a shapefile that has a table like this. Both the class (DESCRIPT) and zone (NAME_2) are ungrouped.
[image]

This is how I want the csv/spreadsheet output file to look like. This was made by a separate stand-alone GeoPandas script.
[image]

Current QGIS processing plugin script

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterField
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Tblt1(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('class', 'Class', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('classfield', 'Class field', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any, parentLayerParameterName='class', allowMultiple=False, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('zone', 'Zone', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVector], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('zonefield', 'Zone field', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any, parentLayerParameterName='zone', allowMultiple=False, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Result', 'Result', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Intersection
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['class'],
            'INPUT_FIELDS': parameters['classfield'],
            'OVERLAY': parameters['zone'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS': parameters['zonefield'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Intersection'] = processing.run('native:intersection', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Add geometry attributes
        alg_params = {
            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
            'INPUT': outputs['Intersection']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Result']
        }
        outputs['AddGeometryAttributes'] = processing.run('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Result'] = outputs['AddGeometryAttributes']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Tabulate Area v1'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Tabulate Area v1'

    def createInstance(self):
        return Tblt1()
```

Comment: How about [csv writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), and Group with Collections.defaultdict(list)? Are they included in QGIS standard libraries (where are the included libraries listed?)?

Comment: Right! So, I could save the output shapefile as CSV then the saved CSV I will modify with the csv library and overwrite it. Thank you, @BERA

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the lead. I'll check it out, @BERA.